# Configuration of ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web project that the front-end is Angular 5 and the back-end is ASP.NET Core. the front-end and back-end are in separated projects.

I have a host with Windows as OS and Plesk as control panel, the Document root folder is `home` and placed in Home directory

I publish my api to `home/api` directory but I get some errors about not started application(502), when I publish my api to `home` directory, I can not access my front-end files and I get `page can’t be found` error

here is my web.config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Api.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Is there any way to publish the API on any folder? like `home/api`

Comment: how do you publish the app?

Comment: @MarcusHöglund by Microsoft Visual studio 2017 and FTP method